# How to vary the contents of a modal popup in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I found this example in Bootstrap documentation about how to vary contents of a modal using JQuery:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var title = button.data('title') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var recipient = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
</script>
```

The problem is that it only seems to change the contents of a form control (input or textarea). My goal is to change the text message but  I didn't manage to do that. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended finding a solution. Someone told anywhere that the modal could be treated as ANY html tag so I just decided to test to access the DOM with Vanilla JS like this:

```js
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var title = button.data('title')
  var body = button.data('body')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title)
  document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = body
})
</script>
```

And inside the modal I created a 'body' div this way:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="body"></div>
</div>
```

Finally the code of the button that opens the modal and passes the data is:

```html
<a class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' data-title='Title text' data-body='Text body'>Launch modal</a>
```